# Run-time error '3061' raised on SELECT - WHERE statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, select, runtime-error, where-clause

New to ACCESS, self learning. Having issue with VBA. The following code runs successfully:

```vb
Sub RentalCalc()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim Adate As Date
Adate = "4/24/2023"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TBL_Rate_Schedule")
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [Reservation_Date], [HITAT_Rate] From TBL_Rate_Schedule")

    Debug.Print [Adate]
    Debug.Print rs![Reservation_Date]
    Debug.Print rs![HITAT_Rate]
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

```
RESULTS:
4/24/2023 
1/1/2023 
 0.1025
```

---

VBA code fails when adding WHERE clause to the code. It is the ONLY difference between code that executes and code that fails. Failed code is, as follows:

```vb
Sub RentalCalc()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim Adate As Date
Adate = "4/24/2023"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TBL_Rate_Schedule")
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [Reservation_Date], [HITAT_Rate] From TBL_Rate_Schedule Where Adate = [Reservation_Date]")

    Debug.Print [Adate]
    Debug.Print rs![Reservation_Date]
    Debug.Print rs![HITAT_Rate]
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Error:
Run-time error ‘3061’:
Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Other info:
Table - TBL_Rate_Schedule
Field Name - Reservation_Date
Data Type - Date/Time

The successful logic produced data from the a record TBL_Rate_Schedule table. It is not the record that I want, but the VBA logic executes without error. The WHERE clause should draw date from the record I want to specify, but this change raised the run-time error.

Comment: most likely change WHERE STATEMENT TO:  Where [Reservation_Date] = #" & Adate#)  Note how it is Reservation_Date = Adate and that Adate is surrounded by the Access VBA date delimiter #  make sure where is part of the string

Answer (score 0):

Either use a query with parameters or concatenate the date value as a formatted text expression:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim Adate As Date
Adate = #4/24/2023#

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [Reservation_Date], [HITAT_Rate] From TBL_Rate_Schedule Where [Reservation_Date] = #" & Format(Adate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider DAO [QueryDef parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). Right now, `ADate` is not recognized in the database connection but only on VBA side. Instead, bind the value safely and efficiently with parameterization.

```vb
Sub RentalCalc() 
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdef As DAO.QueryDef, rs As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim sql As String
    Const Adate As Date: Adate = CDate("4/24/2023")

    sql = "PARAMETERS prmAdate DATETIME; " _
           & "SELECT [Reservation_Date], [HITAT_Rate] " _
           & "FROM TBL_Rate_Schedule " _
           & "WHERE [Reservation_Date] = prmAdate"

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", sql)
    qdef!prmAdate = Adate

    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset() 

    Debug.Print [Adate] 
    Debug.Print rs![Reservation_Date]
    Debug.Print rs![HITAT_Rate] 

    rs.Close 
    Set rs = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing 
End Sub
```